# Java Could not find Main class

Tags: java

I have a short question i have wrote this in java.
Old code:

```
   class apples{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("hello Youtube");
        }
    }
```

New code

```
public class apples{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("hello Youtube");
        }
    }
```

Eclipse give me this error:

*Error: Could not find or load main class apples*

What am I doing wrong? I am watching this tutorial from bucky : [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHIT5VkNrCg&feature=bf_prev&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28)

*Second Question:*

In the tutorial there is something like Auto complete. How can I turn this on in eclipse?

**FIXED: openend a file instead of class thanks for al the help!**

Comment: With the code edition you've made to the question, now it's unclear what was the problem. People will eventually read perfectly correct code and wonder...

Comment: Maybe then something is wrong with the install of my java/eclipse because if this code is correct it still keep saying : Error: Could not find or load main class apples

Comment: well, have you used any package for this class (although this should not be a problem, it's a good practice)?

Comment: what's the filename of your class file?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial on youtube.

Comment: maybe you need to start over, check out this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava

Comment: @hovanessyan I will do.
Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have a `public` class for the main method to be recognizable by the JVM.

Also, try to make use of package declarations. You can have something simple such as `package com.foo.examples;`.

For your second question: Autocomplete is turned on by default in Eclipse. In fact, I don't know how to turn it off!

Just use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> in various places and see what happens. You can also type in a class say, `System` followed by a dot and see all the autocompletion entries for the visible static methods of `System` class.

Comment: Should this work? I edited the code! @MarkoTopolnik I will soon.

Comment: @JochemTheSchoolKid Please try.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I litteraly copy pasted you code in to eclipse and it still give me the error : Error: Could not find or load main class apples
document is called : apples.java

Comment: in my case the file name is Main.java and class including main method name is Main

Answer (score 0):

For the second question :

By Autocomplete, you probably mean "Content Assist"

You can configure it through :

```
Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preferably to use packages and declare the main method as public, but not necessary. You've made a mistake in the line 3 -- it should end with semi :

```
System.out.println("hello Youtube");
```

For Q2, the autocompletion cases appears with control-space hotkey (by default) while you're typing the code.

UPD: sorry, you MUST declare the main method public, but it's not necessary to make a class public

Answer (score 0):

The method must be declared public and static, it must not return any value, and it must accept a String array as a parameter.
The method declaration has the following form:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Your code here
    System.exit(0); //Ending the program and return the given code (0 here)
}
```

sorry for the second question.